# How do I use a mapped network drive when not connected to network?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

I have mapped drive S: on ThisComputer to \\ThisComputer\DocumentsFolder when I am attached to the network, and it works fine. Other computers on the network need to see this drive S: too, and are mapped in the same way.

When I am not connected to the network, I cannot access drive S:.

Is there a way to trick the computer into thinking I am attached to the network?

Using Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised you wouldn't be able to do this as I used to do something similar.

This obviously won't help with other machines - you will want to take a look at Offline Files ([Link 1 - nice guide](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/mobility/learnmore/offlinefiles.mspx), [Link 2 - KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307853)).

For the local machine, you can trick it with the `SUBST` Command, simply type `SUBST x: c:\test` which should create a virtual X drive that is from c:\test,

If it is still failing, this is a guess -
Do you have any firewall software that has roles e.g. when on different networks can configure different permissions? My guess would be that it could be blocking file sharing when on a network other than home/the default connection.

Comment: i feel flattered that you copied my link and refer to it as a 'nice guide'.

Comment: I made sure XP was fully up to date with the latest service packs, then went offline and turned off the firewall (ZoneAlarm) and now it works. I have since turned ZoneAlarm back on and it still works. Offline Files was turned on, but I checked that after I did the update.
So thanks! :)